# В первом часе радопередачи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли так говорить:

**В первом часе** мы расскажем о.... **Во втором часе** мы встретимся с....?

Речь идет о радиопередаче, которая длится два часа.

Есть ли другие допустимые варианты (например, "на первом часе")?

Вариант "в течение первого часа мы расскажем..." кажется слишком формальным, к тому же создается впечатление, что обещанный рассказ займет весь первый час, а это не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В первом часе радиопередачи** ― это "в первой части радиопередачи", управление предложным падежом, **традиционный оборот речи**.

Примеры: **В первом часе** эфира блиц-опрос.  **В последнем часе** утреннего эфира первая пара ведущих  ежедневно обсуждает самые актуальные, интересные и злободневные темы вместе с гостями.

Вариант с предлогом НА: Тема **на первый час**: «Подружитесь с прошлым – научитесь отпускать негатив".

Comment: И как понимать "Тема на первый час"? Также как и "халиф на час", то есть эта тема займет ровно час, а не часть его?

Comment: Должно быть, имеется  виду,  что займет бОльшую часть первого часа, станет его основной темой.

Comment: А если тема займет несколько минут, но подходит для первого часа, тогда "тема для первого часа". Так?

Comment: Думаю, что так можно сказать.